# Bootstrap code design modfication

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Bootstrap in my application. I am trying to make it so my whole left side is `#fff`, while rest is `#f9f9f9`.

This is what I have so far.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      // Left side
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
     // Right side side-bar
   </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
. container {
  width: 1200px !important;
}
```

**PS: I don't want/need responsive design.**

*Image below is a example for what I want to achieve.*
[image]

Here is a [link that hast the same design](http://diply.com/boy-heals-cancer-patients-with-teddy-bears?publisher=different-solutions).

Comment: You can just add a class to each div such as: class="col-xs-8 leftside" and class="col-xs-4 rightside" and then you set the styling for the classes.

Comment: Why would you use Bootstrap instead of plain html if you don't want responsive design?

Comment: Because I have already added it on all pages and rewritten everything takes time.

Comment: @user6589814, instead `container` use `container-fluid` and wrap columns in `div class="row"`

Comment: @IgorIvancha and had to do left and right side?

Comment: if you need indents, just use class 'offset'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="content">
        <div class="col-xs-8 left-side">
        // Left side
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 side-bar">
        // Right side side-bar
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%
}
.content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.left-side{
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.side-bar{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.no-margin{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HENOK. It works fine but `.container` needs to be `1200px` otherwise it will then be responsive and I don't want responsive.

Comment: Oh, in that case, why don't you just try changing the background of body. "body: background-color: #f9f9f9". It makes it seem better but you still don't get to use the extra few pixels off of the side-bar.

Comment: yes that fixes the issue for right side, but left sides `#fff` will then not be good

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to achieve what you want to do.

```css
.leftside {
  background: #fff;
}

.rightside {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 leftside">
      // Left side
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 rightside">
      // Right side side-bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget that Bootstrap columns should be rapped in an `.row` element.

Comment: True. I adapted the snippet

Comment: Thanks @Felix but it doesn't work as I wanted. If you add `body{background:green;}` you can see that it doesn't wrapp the whole left or right side. If you take a look the image, I have the whole left side `#fff` & right side `#f9f9f9`

Comment: I didn't set a height. If you set a height, then as much is grey or white as you wish!